# Sorting a 2 dimensional array

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I've got a 2D array that I'd like to sort into descending order depending on the contents of the first column, however I'd like the array to retain each row and move the second column as the first moves. To put it into an example;

```
[2, 5]
[4, 18]
[1, 7]
[9, 3]
```

would be sorted into:

```
[9, 3]
[4, 18]
[2, 5]
[1, 7]
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm so confused about this. It looks like you have a 1D array of pairs of ints. That's not the same as a 2D array.

Comment: That is so a 2D array :) It's an array of arrays. A value can be referenced as arr[0][1];

Comment: I know what the presentation of a 2D array is. However what he's asking doesn't really make sense. Does have a x by 2 array that really should be one array of just pairs? EDIT: OK after looking at some of the answers it looks like that this is just a really really bad use of 2D arrays (imo anyways). The OP would do better if he just had an array of objects that acted as pairs for the ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[][] d2 = {
           {2,5},
           {4,18},
           {1,7},
           {9,3}
          };

java.util.Arrays.sort(d2, new java.util.Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] a, int[] b) {
        return b[0] - a[0];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    int[][] test = new int[][]{{2,5}, {4,18}, {1,7},{9,3}};
    Arrays.sort(test, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            return o2[0] - o1[0];
        }
    });
```

I haven't tested this but it should work. Note you may want to reverse the subtraction to change descending.

Comment: woops i thought you meant second item in the array. I changed index to 0.

Comment: If you want to this to work for negative integers, use `<` and `>` instead of returning the difference. Otherwise, the difference can overflow the `int` range.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing but Radix Sort. Its C code is as follows:

```
void Rsort(int *a, int n)
{
  int i, b[MAX], m = a[0], exp = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (a[i] > m)
      m = a[i];
  }

  while (m / exp > 0)
  {
    int bucket[10] =
    {  0 };
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      bucket[a[i] / exp % 10]++;
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
      bucket[i] += bucket[i - 1];
    for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      b[--bucket[a[i] / exp % 10]] = a[i];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
      a[i] = b[i];
    exp *= 10;
 }
}
```

Here it's operating on digits of the numbers in array. It's not much harder to edit the code to get code for the above problem. Here each element of the array is considered as a digit for that ROW NUMBER.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to java specifically but the algorithm should be translatable. The point is to move both elements (or more) of the row when swapping.

> int var[ n ][ 2 ] // your int array
>   // [[ choose a sort method ]]
>   // I'm going to use a bubble sort
>   // for clarity, despite inefficiency
>   int temp[ 2 ];
>   bool stillSorting = true;
>   do
>   {
>
> > stillSorting = false;
> >     for ( int x = n; x < 1; x-- )
> >     {
> >
> > > if ( var[ x ][ 0 ] > var[ x-1 ][ 0 ] )
> > >       {
> > >
> > > > temp[ 0 ] = var[ x ][ 0 ]; // if it's more than 2
> > > >         temp[ 1 ] = var[ x ][ 1 ]; // consider using a loop
> > > >         var[ x ][ 0 ] = var[ x-1 ][ 0 ];
> > > >         var[ x ][ 1 ] = var[ x-1 ][ 1 ];
> > > >         var[ x-1 ][ 0 ] = temp[ 0 ];
> > > >         var[ x-1 ][ 1 ] = temp[ 1 ];
> > > >         stillSorting = true;
> > > >         }
> > > >         }
> > > >         }
> > > >         while( stillSorting );

Comment: Which programming language is this?

Comment: It is just novice pseudocode in C++ style, as that's all I was familiar with at the time.