# Sort 2d array by 2nd dimension

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array

I need to sort my items depending on their price.

The price of each item is stored in a JSON array

I have created a 2d array to store the name and price

Something like this...

```
    String [][] priceArray = new String [itemArray.length()] [2];

    for(int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++)
    {
        //put the item name in the first dimension
        priceArray[i][0] = itemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

        //put the item price in the second dimension        
        priceArray[i][1] = itemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("baseprice");       
    }

    //DEBUG TO SEE THE RESULTS
    for(int i = 0; i < priceArray.length; i++)
    {
        Log.i("Item name : Item Price", priceArray[i][0] + " : " + priceArray[i][1]);               
    }
```

This works fine... but how can i sort the array by the price in the second dimension?

Is this even the best way to do this?

Comment: why the android tag? you realize that adding unrelated tags can cause people to ignore your post?

Comment: See these links for related questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158679/sorting-a-2-dimensional-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907683/sort-a-two-dimensional-array-based-on-one-column http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321123/need-help-sorting-two-dimensional-arrays-by-second-element-and-then-by-first-ele

Comment: @Majid L It is actually for an android app...I will make this clearer in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do this: take advantage of OO programming, first, create a class Item to contain name and price:

```
class Item {
    String name;
    BigDecimal price;

    public String toString() { return "ITEM: {name:" + name + ", price: " + price + "}" }
}
```

then create a list of Items rather than a 2D array:

```
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

for(int i = 0; i < itemArray.length(); i++)
{
    Item item = new Item();
    item.name = itemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    item.price = new BigDecimal(itemArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("baseprice"));
    items.add(item);
}
```

Finally, you can order by name if you want:

```
// Sort by name
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }

});

// at this point, items will be ordered by name
```

or if you want to order by price:

```
// Sort by price
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<Item>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
        return o1.price.compareTo(o2.price);
    }
});

// at this point, items will be ordered by price
```

Of course, I'm missing some minor issues like using getters and setters instead of accessing the fields of `Item` directly, but the intention is to show the idea.

Comment: I have tried exactly this...but when i print the results to test, I get: "{packagename}.ItemList$Item@41f6ba68" <-- the last number changes

Comment: I updated my answer, I added `toString()` to `Item` so when you use `System.out.println()` it prints a more friendly result

Comment: I have figured out what i was doing wrong now...it works how i wanted it to now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you create your own entity Price. And in your loop create List of Price entities with "name" and "baseprice" values. Then you can sort your list using [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)
and your own Comparator in wich you can specify way how to compare Price objects.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure i fully understand, could you possibly provide a code example?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're in [object denial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3725728/2095090). Still, it's relatively easy to sort a two dimensional array on an arbitrary column. Just use a custom comparator. (Error checking for column existence is omitted in the snippet below.)

```
Arrays.sort(priceArray, new Comparator<String[]> {
    final int sortColumn = 1;

    @Override
    public int compare(String[] left, String right) {
        return left[sortColumn].compareTo(right[sortColumn]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 int[][] array2D = {{1,1},{3,21},{5,8},{10,8}};

    Arrays.sort(array2D, new Comparator<int[]>() {
        public int compare(int[] first, int[] second) {
            return first[1] - second[1];
        }
    });
```